# Best approach to merging back SVN branch to trunk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, svn, ankhsvn

I appreciate there has been some comment on this, but I am wondering whether my situation is a little different.

I am using MVC3 and VS2012. I have a solution with 2 projects, one for the web app and the other for the DB domain model.

I use TortoiseSVN as well as AnkhSVN within VS2012.

I have created a branch off the trunk where I have made quite a few changes including new DLLs and associated references. One of the big changes is upgrading Entity Framework to 6.1.1 from 5. So new dlls and namespace definitions.

The trunk has been tweaked to address some urgent mods.

I have checked out the trunk and branch into seperate local folders, and work on each seperately.

Normally, as I understand it, when one is ready to remerge the branch to trunk, one uses SVN, but this can be error prone. I am a big fan of Beyond Compare, and used it before SVN. I now use it as my diff tool within SVN. I could use Beyond Compare to copy across the modified code from the branch local folder to the trunk local folder and then "commit" the local changes back to "trunk", but this local copy across, while being robust, is very tedious.

I would be grateful if one could provide a better recommendation.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you're using svn a bit wrong. What is error prone about svn? I had no problems with it for years before moving to git. Firstly it sounds like you need to check in your branch and your trunk, then just merge into trunk on your local machine, just it works, then check it in

Comment: You might want to look at the switch command when working with branches.

Comment: @matt_lethargic, thank you for this. I had picked up that some folk had had issues when merging branches back into Trunk. Apparently Git is much better at this than SVN. I will try out the SVN merge tool.

Comment: No probs. lol, If it was prone to errors no one would use it!!